# Ошибка при "клонировании" проекта GitHub через VS Community 2013

Tags: visual-studio, github

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой:

При клонировании (clone) репозитория через VS Community 2013 из GitHub - возникает ошибка "An error occurred. Detailed message: An error occurred while sending the request."

Для теста делаю всё стандартными шагами:

1. Создаю новый паблик репозиторий на GitHub
2. В VS открываю Team Explorer
3. Нажимаю Clone - ввожу ссылку GitHub репозитория и выбираю папку куда клонировать

В итоге получаю вышеуказанную ошибку

Пробовал одно из найденных в гугле решений - это правка файла devenv.exe.config, добавления в него строки

Но, к сожалению, не помогло

Заранее благодарен за советы!

Comment: Nick Volynkin, к сожалению нет возможности установить git bash, т.к. я не администратор своего ПК. Возможно из-за этого и ошибка возникает?

Comment: Описание ошибки очень общее выдает.
Вот что, попробуйте сделать где-нибудь на своей машине локальный репозиторий и подключить его. В качестве адреса указывайте локальный путь. Если сработает - дело в соединении с гитхабом, если нет - то VS сломалась где-то.

Comment: Да, если вы на работе - просите, чтобы админ пришел и установил вам Git Bash и все необходимые инструменты.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал создать локальный - всё работает нормально, а вот работать с GitHub'ом он отказывается почему-то. Думаете это может быть из-за того что у меня не установлен Git ? Просто на моём домашнем ПК тоже нет Git'a, но всё работает

Comment: А как вы создали локальный, если Git не установлен? Я имел в виду создать локальный и подключить его как remote. `git remote add local C:/temp/.git`

Comment: Я создал через Team Explorer в студии. Т.к. пока возможности установить Git нет, процедура у нас, уж очень долгая в компании, бюрократия.. (

Comment: клонировали через какой протокол? какой адрес давали VS для клонирования? Скорее всего HTTPS, попробуйте еще SSH, это вида `git@github.com:...`

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал SSH, к сожалению, выдаёт тоже ошибку, но уже другую: "Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid"

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, ошибка в адресе. Должно выглядеть так: git@github.com:NickVolynkin/args4j.git

Comment: Да, в таком формате и есть, я копирую из GitHub, там можно выбрать три варианта: You can clone with  HTTPS, SSH, or Subversion.